# How to make label location relative to mouse position

Tags: wpf

i have a label and i wanna change it's location corresponding to mouse position, my problem is the label location !,it's relative to a application windows, how could i change coordinates to make them relative to screen coordinates.
thank you
sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the mouse coordinates (relative to the window) to the location of the window on the desktop.